# Error in Windows service

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I have windows service, when i try to pass data to it. I get this error.

Any idea what i'm missing?

> There was an error reflecting type
>   'LHC.Impilo.Preadmission.Common.Domain.PreadmissionEvent[]'

This is class below:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall,
    TransactionIsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single,
    ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete = false)]
[CustomErrorBehaviour(WrapErrors = false)]
[Serializable]
public class PartnerPreadmissionService : IPartnerPreadmissionService
{
```

Comment: How are you "passing" data to it? What web-service technology are you using (e.g. WCF? WebAPI?)? What is a PreadmisionEvent? What is the full exception, including the stack trace? Please read http://whathaveyoutried.com for advice on asking a good question :)

Comment: What does the `PreadmissionEvent` type look like?  The most common reason for this is that the type lacks a public parameterless constructor, but there are many other possibilities.  Impossible to say without either the code or the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the message, traceback, and inner exceptions.